# OpenCart, где править калькулятор цен товаров?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, opencart

Здравствуйте, девелоперы!
На опенкарт, дописываю свой модуль, делаю ручное управление цен, по этому дописовал и переписывал валюту, но калькулятор, при заказе(то есть в корзине) еще считает старые цены, не подскажите где править этот калькулятор, ибо файл перерыл, как конфигы так и шаблон, но чтоб ничего рабочего не нашел

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]